# NEXT-AUTH Sigin error callback with next-auth on production

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, oauth, next-auth

I have a project build vith next and next-auth for authentication
On my local , run wirh 'yarn dev', everything is ok
On my build , run with 'yarn build' and 'yarn start', everything is ok
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id2ON.png)But when i deploy it to production, i recieve a callback error signin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45UBq.png)

I have seen some issue on github about use NEXTAUTH_SECRECT in config env but it not working with me
here is my next auth config

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    LineProvider({
      clientId: process.env.LINE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    InstagramProvider({
      clientId: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_SECRET_KEY,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: { scope: undefined },
      },
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'ginCustomProvider',
      name: 'ginCustomProvider',
      credentials: {
        token: { type: 'text' },
      },
      async authorize(
        credentials
      ): Promise<Required<User & token & tokenGin> | null> {
        if (!credentials) return null;
        const res = await authSocialGin(credentials.token);
        if (!res) {
          return null;
        }
        return res;
      },
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'credentials',
      type: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials): Promise<Required<User & token> | null> {
        const res = await credentialLogin({
          username: credentials?.username,
          password: credentials?.password,
        });
        if (!res) {
          return null;
        }
        return res;
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  theme: {
    colorScheme: 'light',
  },
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: 'accessToken',
      options: { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'lax', path: '/', secure: true },
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      try {
        if (account && account?.provider === 'google' && account?.id_token) {
          const res = await authSocialGoogle(account.id_token);
          if (
            user &&
            isTokenExpired((<any>res)?.accessToken) &&
            (<any>res)?.refreshToken
          ) {
            const response = await requestToken((<any>res)?.refreshToken);
            return { ...token, ...response };
          }
          return {
            ...token,
            ...res,
            ...user,
          };
        }
        if (
          account &&
          account?.provider === 'instagram' &&
          account?.access_token
        ) {
          const res = await authSocialInstagram(account.access_token);
          if (
            user &&
            isTokenExpired((<any>res)?.accessToken) &&
            (<any>res)?.refreshToken
          ) {
            const response = await requestToken((<any>res)?.refreshToken);
            return { ...token, ...response };
          }
          return {
            ...token,
            ...res,
            ...user,
          };
        }
        if (
          account &&
          account?.provider === 'facebook' &&
          account?.access_token
        ) {
          const res = await authSocialFaceBook(account.access_token);
          if (
            user &&
            isTokenExpired((<any>res)?.accessToken) &&
            (<any>res)?.refreshToken
          ) {
            const response = await requestToken((<any>res)?.refreshToken);
            return { ...token, ...response };
          }
          return {
            ...token,
            ...res,
            ...user,
          };
        }
        if (account && account?.provider === 'line' && account?.id_token) {
          const res = await authSocialLine(account.id_token);
          return {
            ...token,
            ...user,
            ...res,
          };
        }
        if (account && account?.provider === 'credentials') {
          return {
            ...token,
            ...user,
          };
        }
        if (account && account?.provider === 'ginCustomProvider') {
          return {
            ...token,
            ...user,
          };
        }
        if (
          token &&
          isTokenExpired(<any>token?.accessToken) &&
          token?.refreshToken
        ) {
          const responseRefreshToken = await requestToken(
            (<any>token)?.refreshToken
          );
          return { ...token, ...responseRefreshToken };
        }
        return token;
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    },
    async session({ session, token }): Promise<Session> {
      const tokenId = token.accessToken;
      try {
        if (tokenId) {
          session.user = tokenId;
        } else {
          session.user = { name: '', email: '' };
        }
        return session;
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      // Allows relative callback URLs
      if (url.startsWith('/ginCustomProvider')) {
        const fullUrl = `${baseUrl}/${url}`;
        return fullUrl.split('?')[0];
      }
      // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
      else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url;
      return baseUrl;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "minakomi-frontend-webpage",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.17",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.0",
    "@sls-next/serverless-component": "3.7.0",
    "ahooks": "^3.7.2",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.6",
    "i18next": "^22.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "next-auth": "4.15.1",
    "next-i18next": "^13.0.0",
    "next-share": "^0.19.0",
    "notistack": "^2.0.8",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.39.3",
    "react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.4",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.2.12",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@types/react": "18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.42.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.42.0",
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.3"
  }
}
```

I don't know about this bug, I've read lots of doccument but can't resolve, so please anyone tell me what's wrong on production